# Correct way to calibrate means

Tags: calibration

I'm working on benchmarking the speed of various JavaScript methods.
Part of the benchmark process requires repeating a test for a minimum time *(to reduce the percentage uncertainty to at or less than 1%)*. There is some overhead on each test *(the cost of the loop, incrementing a counter variable and so on)*. I currently benchmark an empty test to get the overhead cost. The result has it's own mean and margin of error. How should I apply this calibration? Do I take the calibration mean and subtract it from every measured value that compose other benchmark samples, or should I subtract it from the other benchmark's mean value even with differences in margin of error, or is their some formula to follow?

Comment: About the flag -- this is no need to remove this post, it may be still useful for others.

Answer (score 5):

There is something called "small error propagation", and it says that the error of a function $f$ of variables $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$ with errors $\Delta x_1,\Delta x_2,\cdots,\Delta x_n$ equals

$$\Delta f=\sqrt{\sum_i\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\Delta x_i\right)^2},$$

so for $f(a,b):=a-b$ the error is $\Delta f=\sqrt{\Delta a^2+\Delta b^2}$.

So, subtract the means and report this euclidean length of errors as a final error.

Comment: So something like `var calibrated = a.mean - cal.mean;` and then take their standard errors `var error = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(a.SEM, 2) + Math.pow(cal.SEM, 2));`? How does that get factored in for reporting margin of error?

Comment: @John Sure; for the second thing, I'm afraid I don't understand... how to call it in a report?

Comment: So how would I report the `error`, if it's not margin of error *(MoE)*, or standard error of the mean *(SEM)*? Would I do something like `moe = error * getCriticalValue(a.size - 1);` similar to if `error` was the SEM?

Comment: I ended up computing the difference between means as the calibrated mean -- http://stattrek.com/AP-Statistics-4/Difference-Means.aspx

Comment: @John-David MOE=SeM=deviation of mean=deviation of sample/$\sqrt{\text{size of sample}}$ -- that's why I used the word "error". So, my result is identical to the magic formula on that site -- they just get deviation of sample as input, which is quite confusing.