# Computing the difference between means and resolving a new/composite sample size

Tags: sample-size, mean

When computing the difference between means I can resolve a new mean, variance, standard error of the mean, and margin of error, but is there a way to compute a new/composite sample size value?

I ask because I use the difference between means as a way to calibrate the mean and later when comparing other calibrated means sample size comes into the formulas.

([Source](https://stattrek.com/sampling/difference-in-means))

#### Update

In the code example below I subtract the calibrations mean from the benchmarks mean time to execute a test. The calibration is an empty test to clock the cost of the benchmarks overhead.
The only part I am missing is how to create a composite sample size (if that is possible).

```
       mean -= cs.mean;
       variance += cs.variance;
       sd = sqrt(variance);
       moe = sd * getCriticalValue(getDegreesOfFreedom(me, cal));
       rme = (moe / mean) * 100;
       extend(me.stats, {
         'ME': moe,
         'RME': rme,
         'deviation': sd,
         'mean': mean,
         'size': ???,
         'variance': variance
       });
```

Comment: It may help if you explain a bit more about *how* you use the difference between means to calibrate the mean.

Comment: @onestop See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6096/correct-way-to-calibrate-means

Comment: Thanks, mbq. Seems to me the overhead would simply cancel out when taking the difference between two overhead-corrected means. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @onestop - I correct the variance, moe, sd, and others but I am not sure if sample size also needs correcting and if so, the formula to do it.

Comment: @mbq - Thanks for helping me clear things up. Still unsure what the composite `n` value would be. The tutorials I have seen don't mention a way to compute it.

Comment: @mbq I found a site that shows formulas for computing the new `n` value -- http://www.rad.jhmi.edu/jeng/javarad/samplesize/

Comment: @mbq Seems that site wasn't much help :(

Comment: @John This site you linked does not contain any equation valid in your case...

Answer (score 1):

I just think you are making it just too complex -- it is a JS benchmark for other programmers, not a clinical trial or Higgs boson search that will be peer reviewed by bloodthirsty referees and later have a great impact.

Just make a non-small number of repetitions (30), of both test and empty test, subtract the means, calculate error of this mean difference as I wrote you before and publish just this -- adding dozens of other measures will only confuse the readers.

Then, for each comparisons, you will have two means $X$ and $Y$ and two errors of that means, respectively $\Delta X$ and $\Delta Y$, so calculate $T$ as

$$T=\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt{(\Delta X)^2+(\Delta Y)^2}},$$

assume $\infty$ degrees of freedom for t-test and you're done. (If you don't believe that $30=\infty$, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution).)

Comment: I replied to you and @onestop in an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

*How* are you comparing the calibrated means? If you're looking at differences between them, and testing if that's zero using a $t$-test, then surely the mean of the empty loop ($\bar{x}_0$, say) will simply cancel out:
$$(\bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_0) - (\bar{x}_2 - \bar{x}_0) = \bar{x}_1 - \bar{x}_2$$

Comment: I replied to you and @mbq in an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mbq and @onestop. After running some tests the calibration was a wash. Subtracting the means raised the margin or error to the point that the calibrated and none calibrated test results where indeterminately different.

@mbq I will take your advice and reduce the critical value lookup to 30 *(as infinity)*.

When comparing against other benchmarks I think I can even avoid the walsh t-test because the variances are so low *(all below 1)*. Some examples are the variances of benchmarks are:
`1.1733873442408789e-16`, `0.000012223589489868368`, `3.772214786601029e-19`, and `6.607725046958527e-16`.